# How to avoid time zone issues with JQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using datepicker in an input form, and sending the results through json to a database. I am using this line, to get the date from the datePicker:

```
date = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
```

Now, I would expect this to return `2014-04-03T00:00:00.000Z`

But in fact it returns `2014-04-02T22:00:00.000Z`

Notice the two hour difference, which unintentionally changes the day of month as well. I have no use for the hours and the smaller time units. However I do want the date to be right, without adding a dreaded `+1` to my code. I suspect this has something to do with time zones, but I can't seem to find a solution to it in the documentation, or other Q&A's online. Could anyone point me in the right direction? My time zone is GMT +1 if that matters.

Thanks :)

Comment: is your OS or browsers time zone correctly configured?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved this a while ago, but forgot to post an answer.
After retrieving `date`, this is how i fixed it:

```
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
```

voilla

Comment: what about if we want to set full date, my selected date displays less by one.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out what you did there so I came up with a bit of a hackterrific solution.

I took the value of the alt field in UNIX:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      altField: "#alternate",
      altFormat: "@",
    });
```

It came out all sorts of weird with 3 extra 0's and a day behind my time zone.
So I figured out the difference and added it on.

```
var a = document.getElementById("alternate").value; // take alternative field UnixTimeStamp value
a = a.slice(0, -3);     // get rid of 3 extra 0's
a = +a + +57000;        // convert to Thai time
```