# JQuery Datepicker getDate return wrong date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time, timezone

I'm using the datepicker from JQuery. When I call the getDate() function it returns the chosen Date -2 hours. Even if I set the hours for example to 15 it returns 13 if I log it in the console.

I guess it's an issue with the timezone, but I don't have a clue how to solve it. If I choose the date 06/16/15 I would like to have 06/16/15 00:00:00 when I have the date and not 06/15/15 22:00:00. Does anyone have a clue how to solve it?

EDIT:

```
var date = $("#from_date").datepicker("getDate");
date.setHours(15);
date.setMinutes(22);
console.log(date);
console.log(new Date());
```

Console Output:
Date 2015-06-01T13:22:00.000Z

Tue Jun 16 2015 15:16:32 GMT+0200

Comment: can you post your js code?

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717201/how-to-avoid-time-zone-issues-with-jquery-datepicker