# datetimepicker plugin selects one hour back after selecting particular time

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using datetimepicker plugin.I am getting a strange error. whenever i am selecting a time from the dropdown ,the plugin selects one hour before of the selected time. Couldn't figure out why this is happening

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Date Time Picker </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" value="2:00 PM" id="timepicker" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
            datepicker: false,
            step:30,
            format:'g:i A'
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The answers i got this post is to Change the **g** in the format option to Capital **G**. but when i changed like this means 12 hours format has been changed to 24 hour format.I want to have it to retain 12 hours format and solve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change format g:i A to H:i A:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Date Time Picker </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" value="2:00 AM" id="timepicker" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
            datepicker: false,
            step:30,
            format:'H:i A'
        });
       $('#timepicker').change(function(){
           $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^0+/, ''));
       });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Govind i have changed as you have mentioned, but the time format has been changed from 12 hour format to 24 hour format.please look at the updated question

Comment: Hi @Govind thanks for the very quick response.please change the value 2:00 AM to 2:00 PM.in that case it's not seems to work fine

Comment: @codegeek According to my research it not possible directly with datetimepicker you need to do it manually as i updated.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are using invalid `format`. Just use `format:'H:i A'` instead of `format:'g:i A'`

```js
$('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
  datepicker: false,
  step: 30,
  format:'H:i A'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />

<input type="text" value="2:00 AM" id="timepicker" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use G Capital:

```
    $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
        datepicker: false, 
        step: 30,
        format:'G:i A'
    });
```

[JSFiddle test](https://jsfiddle.net/d8j3patm/#&togetherjs=edx84TiJGv)

Answer (score 1):

Usually when working with dates and time, differences with +-1 hour / day etc. has to to with time zone differences. 
 1. Se if the plugin has a time zone config parameter.
 2. Account for time zone offset yourself by adding 1 hour.

See: [How to avoid time zone issues with JQuery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717201/how-to-avoid-time-zone-issues-with-jquery-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I came across it while looking for a solution so I figured I should post it for anyone else having the same issue. I was also disappointed that the solution was just to use 24 hour format...

After reading this thread: [Format "m/d/Y h:i a" changes hour onBlur](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/596)
I switched my date formatter to "moment", which should already be included, and changed my formatting to the appropriate "moment" conventions and the 1 hour issue is gone:

```
$.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter('moment');
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A',
    formatTime: 'h:mm A',
    formatDate: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
});
```